# is declaring a Business Layer object as public property in a asp.net masterpage a good move?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, data-access-layer, business-layer

Im currently working in a ASP.Net C# application and i am using the DAL design pattern with Datasets and Business layers.

Normally when i request data in my c# code i create a business layer object:

```
BLLAccount oblAccount = new BLLAccount();
```

then i can work with it by calling the functions i declared in BLLAccount: oblAccount.GetAccounts();

this routine is repeated on every page and with every data request within every event scope. You can understand this gets annoying fast so i declared a page property so i dont have to recreate the same object every time:

```
private BLLAccount m_BLLAccount = null;
    public BLLAccount oblAccount
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_BLLAccount == null)
            {
                m_BLLAccount = new BLLAccount();
            }
            return m_BLLAccount;
        }
    }
```

this way the object is only created at the time i need it, and can be re-used in every event scope. this is usefull on a page, but now i am creating many pages, and even this solution is getting annoying. the first thing i tought of was that i am currently using masterpages and childpages, so why not put the page property on the masterpage, refere to the masterpage in my aspx using this little snippet?

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master.master" %>
```

and in my code refer to it in this way:

```
Master.oblAccount.GetAccounts();
```

this works cool and really well, but i'm unsure what impact this has on the memory of the server and the performance of the application. will my page property be cleaned up if unused too long or not? will the initial load be too heavy? is it better to create a constructor on the business layer itself or doen't that part matter much?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't profile your application for you.  This is something you should try to do. There are lots of great profilers out there.  The Profiler would also be able to tell you what sticks around in memory (through each generation) and what's not being garbage collected.  What you do with those results is up to you.  Whether or not this is a 'good practice' is entirely centered around your company culture and your specific use case, as well as what painpoints you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it in the MasterPage seems like overkill.  How about creating a class that inherits from `Page` and have all of your pages that need access to the data layer inherit from that class.

Comment: How much does that defer from putting it in the masterpage if practically every page requeres atleast 2-3 Business layers? Will the server load be lesser with the inherited page class and will the business object properties be recreated wich each unique page call? If the last part is true your solution sounds like a better practice

Comment: I decided to go with this practice, it works well and keeps the masterpage clean. This solution also sounds like working better with the garbage collector altough more detailed research will give a final on the latter. thnx for the tip George Stocker!

Comment: I think the server load will be nearly the same, only difference would be pages that don't need the business objects at all.  Also, since you are lazy initializing, you're not even creating instances of those classes until they are needed.

Any concern about performance of this would probably fall under premature optimization at this point.